# Query to get documents ordered by key1 ascending, and key2 descending using CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

How I can get documents ordered by key1 (ascending) and key2 (descending) in a view?

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say sort by key1 and key2, you mean "sort by key1 and use key2 to break the ties" right?

Comment: example in SQL ->"SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY key1 ASC, key2 DESC"

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting question, the only answer I can think of is to write a map function that emits as key an array containing the asc key and the "opposite" of the desc key:

```
emit([doc.ascKey, opposite(doc.descKey)], doc);
```

The opposite function should iterate characters of the desc key to calculate the "alphabetical opposite" of them; for simplicity in ASCII it would be something like this pseudo-code snippet:

```
var oppositeStr = "";
for (char in str) {
  oppositeStr += chr(255 - char);
}
```

My solution is just speculative, but may also work! Maybe someone has a better idea?